# Can I distribute Wolfram.NETLink.dll with an open-source project?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, .netlink, licensing, open-source, free-wolfram-engine

I am developing an open-source suite of Windows Workflow Foundation activities for the Wolfram Language to use with UiPath, a Windows automation platform. I built it using the Wolfram.NETLink library.

However, from my understanding of the Wolfram Engine Free License For Developers, I cannot redistribute *any* part of the Wolfram system. This is despite the NETLink documents stating that the DLL must be redistributed with anything for it to work ([See Deploying Programs here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/NETLink/tutorial/CallingTheWolframLanguageFromNET.html)), since it is not a strongly named DLL.

If I do not include the DLL with my NuGet package, it becomes much more difficult for someone to use my project, since the DLL cannot be located and used in UiPath's Studio UI.

Can anyone that is familiar with the Wolfram license ecosystem and open-source wolfram projects let me know what I can do?

Edit:

So basically the question comes down to which of these licenses applies to the .NETLink dll (which is essentially a MathLink wrapper).
[MathLink](https://www.wolfram.com/legal/agreements/mathlink.html) or [Wolfram Engine](https://www.wolfram.com/legal/terms/wolfram-engine.html)

I think it may be more applicable to abide by the MathLink license, since that component is available in other Mathematica versions / programs, so it isn't necessarily part of the Engine.

Comment: WRI's support can probably help you with this question, and it would also give you greater peace of mind to get the answer from them.

Comment: Thanks, I just messaged their support. Was hoping i wasn't the only one with this question, considering the DLL is being redistributed without the MathLink license all over GitHub...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To follow up on this: WRI did respond to me and had no issue with redistribution of the MathLink dll as a NuGet package, and are planning on creating their own package in the future. For now, I'm using a self-packaged NuGet package containing this DLL and their licensing information.